# How to enable/disable specific item in selectManyCheckbox on ajax keyUp

Tags: ajax, list, jsf, primefaces, selectmanycheckbox

I need your help in enabling/disabling a specific item in the `selectManyCheckbox` component based on the ajax call keyup.

When the page loads, I am firing the below method to populate the `selectManyCheckbox` items in the form:

```
 @PostConstruct

    public void init() throws SQLException {

    this.hrCertificatesList.add(new hrCertificate(("Employment"), "CE", false));

    this.hrCertificatesList.add(new hrCertificate(("Loan"), "LC", false));

}
```

And here is the jsf code:

```
  <p:inputText id="selectedEmployee" value="#{HRRequest.selectedEmployeeCode}">

     <p:ajax event="keyup" update="employeeName" listener="#{HRRequest.getEmployeeName}" />

   </p:inputText>

<h:outputText id="employeeName" value="#{HRRequest.selectedEmployeeName}" />

<p:selectManyCheckbox id="hrCertificates" value="#{HRRequest.selectedHRCertificates}">
 <f:selectItems value="#{HRRequest.hrCertificatesList}" var="hrCertificate" 
itemLabel="#{hrCertificate.hrCertificateName}"
    itemValue="#{hrCertificate.hrCertificateCode}" itemDisabled="#{hrCertificate.hrBooleanCertificate}"/>

    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Once the page loads, all the checkboxes are enabled and when the user enters employeeCode in the `inputText`, an ajax will be fired to call a method to get the employeeName and to check whether has loan or not, if has loan, then the checkbox should be enabled, otherwise disabled.

To summarize my issue, what I want is that when the value of the variable temp equals to yes, then I need to disable the loan checkbox only and the other item Employment should remain enable, so how can I do this?

The bean code is:

```
 public String getEmployeeName() throws SQLException {
     if (temp.equals("Yes"))
{ 
//How to enable and disable the Loan checkbox only and to update the form view
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":HRform:hrCertificates");    
}
```

So can you please help.

Comment: @BalusC I have edited the topic to be more clear and explained the code more, so can you please guide and assist

Comment: @BalusC hrBooleanCertificate I defined it in the hrCertificate class. The hrBooleanCertificate is referring to the boolean false which is in the init() method where at the beginning all the checkboxes should be enabled, but then I do not know what to do next for setting the Loan item disabled

Comment: So you mean that I should define in my bean a new boolean variable called hrBooleanCertificate and to initialize it to false by default and then in the IF statement to make it true if yes or false if no based on the condition and then to update the component?Will this only be done to the loan checkbox?

Comment: @BalusC is the above correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just manipulate the model in such way that `itemDisabled="#{hrCertificate.hrBooleanCertificate}"` evaluates `true` instead of `false` so that the view knows what it must do.

One way might be:

```
this.hrCertificatesList.get(1).setHrBooleanCertificate(true);
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and come back to you. One more thing, should I update the @form?

Comment: You should indeed update the view if you'd like to reflect changes in the model.

Comment: Thanks for the assistant and help. It worked fine, Awesome